# How to find whether html tag contains content or not - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Title means my question :-)

For example:

```
<html>
...
..
.
<p></p>
.
..
...
</html>
```

**How can i able to find whether that "p" tag is empty or not using Jquery....**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`$(`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)[`"p"`](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)[`)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)[`.is(`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)[`":empty"`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)[`)`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
if($('p:empty').length > 0) { ... }
```

...where `p` is the normal selector you'd use for your `<p>` tag, as per your example -- in a normal HTML page, you'd probably use an ID to uniquely identify it.

The `:empty` selector filters the rest of the selector so the results only contain elements which are empty.

The `'.length` property gives you the number of elements returned by the selector. Therefore, combined with the `:empty` selector, if `.lenth` is zero, then the element isn't empty, and if it equals 1 then it is empty.

- JQuery `:empty` selector manual page: http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/
- JQuery `.length` propery manual page: http://api.jquery.com/length/